# Can I have tasks under one DAG with different start dates in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG which runs two tasks: `A` and `B`.

Instead of specifying the `start_date` on DAG level, I have added it as an attribute to the operators (I am using a `PythonOperator` in this case) and removed it form the DAG dictionary. Both tasks run daily.

The `start_date` for `A` is 2013-01-01 and the `start_date` for `B` is 2015-01-01. My problem is that Airflow runs for 16 days for tasks A (because I guess in my `airflow.cfg` I have left the default `dag_concurrency = 16`)from 2013-01-01 and after that it stops. The DAGs are in state `running` and the tasks for `B` are in state with `no status`.

Clearly I am doing something wrong and I can simply set the `start_date` on DAG level and have `B` run from the `start_date` of `A`, but that's not what i want to do.

Alternatively I can split them in separate DAGs, but again, that's not how I want to monitor them.

Is there a way to have a DAG with multiple tasks each having its own `start_date`? If so, how to do this?

**UPDATE:**

I know that a [`ShortCircuitOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.ShortCircuitOperator) can be added, but this seems to work only for a flow of tasks which are dependent and there is a downstream. In my case `A` is independent of `B`.

Comment: How about SubDagOperator?

Comment: How can I use this to achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case? If the tasks are completely idempotent, just make two DAGs.

Comment: They are completely idempotent, but it makes logical sense to group them as they are very similar.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`BranchPythonOperator`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.2/code.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.BranchPythonOperator) and check in that task that your **execution_date** >= '2015-01-01' or not. If true it should execute **Task B**, if not it should execute a Dummy Task.

[image]

However, I would recommend using a Separate DAG.

Documentation on branching: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.2/concepts.html#branching

Comment: Adding a dummy task does not sound like a very good deasing. Could you please provide an example and also advice whether this is indeed the best way to address such issues? Wouldn't having two DAGs be cleaner?

Comment: After reading about this operation, it does not do what I wish it ides, since it branches, so when I check the UI, the job will not be "skipped"

Comment: @Newskooler I would definitely recommend using a separate DAG but I read in the comments below the question that you are looking for a different solution other than separating it to another DAG. Also, have a look at https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.2/concepts.html#branching - which explains branching in more detail. And would should in the UI if your task is skipped. I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: I have about 750k tasks with different start dates. In this case, would you still have them as separate DAGs?

Comment: If you have 750k tasks, I am sure you are generating them dynamically, if so use BranchPythonOperator. I would have separated them as different DAGs based on logically-dependent groups. If that wasn't possible, I would have used BranchPythonOperator so that I can see when a task was skipped or ran.

Comment: Yes, I am constricting them dynamically. Okay so two questions from this answer:
1. How do I know if a task is skipped by using BranchPythonOp? When a dummy task executes, does this mark it as skipped?
2. Since I am constructing them dynamically, there can be different number of task on a given execution date, is this a bad design and how should this be handles in Airflow? I couldn't find any advice on best practices when it comes to this.