# How to manage a million airflow tasks with different start dates?

Tags: airflow

I have about one million Airflow tasks which use the same python function. Each need to run with a different start date and parameters.

Earlier I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329782/can-i-have-tasks-under-one-dag-with-different-start-dates-in-airflow) on how to run two such tasks under one DAG. However, when the tasks become many, the answers there are not scalable. (see link and notes)

**Question**

How can I run a million (or any large number) or tasks under in a scalable fashion on Airflow, where each tasks stems from the same python function but has a different start date and different arguments?

**Notes**

The tasks don't need to run on a [`PythonOperator`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.PythonOperator) (as they stem from a python function). In reality, they would run in a distributed fashion on a Kubernetes Cluster most likely (so with a [`KubernetesExecutor`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kubernetes.html#kubernetes-executor) or [`KubernetesPodOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/kubernetes.html#airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator)). Either way, the architectural problem behind the contribution of the DAG(s) still remains.)

**Solution ideas**

One solution which I was thinking of is that under one DAG, to dynamically construct all tasks and within the python function which gets executed, to pass the different start dates. On the outside Airflow will execute each task every day, but inside the function, if the `execution_date` is earlier than the `start_date`, the function will just `return 0`.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail?  This sounds like a lot of work; are you prepared to throw an army of machines at it so that it finishes before the heat death of the universe?

Comment: Sure, let me know what kind of information would be used to add? I have limited it to one clear question now.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  I once worked for a company that had a similar workflow arrangement.  I can't imagine the number of tasks being in the thousands, let alone the millions, so I think I'm missing something here (by at least three orders of magnitude).

Comment: Here is an example: Say I have a million users. Each of them joined my network at a different date (so has a different start date). Everyone has its activity saved in daily .json files. If I want to download this date to work for, I need to have a task fro each users. They would all have different start dates and the function I use to download would have a different argument (e.g. the user name). Your comment is suggesting that I may be thinking about the issue in the wrong way I guess.

Comment: You are thinking about it wrong way. Airflow *can* be used in millions of dynamic tasks, but it *should not*. Airflow DAGs are supposed to be pretty constant. I suggest you to use another tools for this problem. You still can use Airflow, for example, to process the whole bunch of users and use this info in your ETL process later.

Comment: @vurmux got it. I guess that's what I needed to know. In this case, what is a good tool to process the thousands/ millions of dynamics task? The tool I will wrap Airflow around essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our conversation in comments I think I can get an answer:

Airflow can be used in millions of dynamic tasks, but it should not. Airflow DAGs are supposed to be pretty constant. You still can use Airflow, for example, to process the whole bunch of users (given from somewhere) and use this info in your ETL process later.

I recommend to build your task system on top of [Celery library](http://www.celeryproject.org/) (don't mess up with the `CeleryExecutor` in Airflow, because Airflow can be used on top of Celery). It is a task queue that is focused on millions of real-time tasks:

> Celery is used in production systems to process millions of tasks a day.

Celery is written on Python, is production-ready, stable and is incredibly scalable. I think it is the best tool to solve your problem.

Comment: I am already running airflow with a `CeleryExecutor`. However when I construct a DAG for say 20130102 it will have 120k tasks and on the next day it will have 150k tasks and a week later it will have 100k tasks. How does the fact that I am using celery help out here? I though it's good to keep the number of tasks constants in a DAG?

Comment: Apache Airflow can work on top of Celery (it is why Airflow is so scalable). I recommend to use the Celery itself, not inside the Airflow. You can write a script that will run 100k tasks with Celery, get their result, and send it to some Airflow task, which will work with them.

Comment: So when you say working with Celery, you don't mean the `CeleryExecutor`, but Celery standalone integrated into my code?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I meant that you can build your code on top of the **Celery library**

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Maybe add this to your reply, so that there is no confusion over the Celery Executor.